# Pass by reference in python: Pass list and add characters?

Tags: python

I'm trying to build a list of commands in a python list `[]` which gets passed to another python object. Nothing crashes but the recipient gets passed a null parameter.

The object is part of a python script menu.py comprised of panel, slot_handler and slot. together they make a scrolling panel object in pygame: panel is the top class. panel has an instance slot_handler which contains slots in a linked list.

I've never tried this before in python. I want to know if this is possible. I'm open to ideas in case this isn't workable.

```
class slot(object):
    def getcommands(self,mylist):
        if(self.has_phrase):
            if(self.phrase=="Move Up"):
                mylist.append('u')
            elif(self.phrase=="Move Down"):
                mylist.append('d')
            elif(self.phrase=="Move Left"):
                mylist.append('l')
            elif(self.phrase=="Move Right"):
                mylist.append('r')
            elif(self.phrase=="Open"):
                mylist.append('o')
            elif(self.phrase=="Close"):
                mylist.append('c')
            elif(self.phrase=="Rotate"):
                mylist.append('s')
        if(self.has_next):
            self.next.getcommands(mylist)

...
class slot_handler(object):
    def getcommands(self):
        commands = []
        self.top_slot.getcommands(commands)

...
class panel(object):
    def getcommands(self):
        return self.slots.getcommands()
```

Comment: "I want to know if this is possible". Did you try it ? Does it fail ?

Comment: On a side note: Your if-elif tree is horrible. Just use a dictionary...

Comment: I solved this by passing in a list variable to panel.getcommands(), I guess python functions can't return a list without falling out of scope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to pass a list as an argument and append to it in a function:

```
>>> def f(x): x.append('u')
...
>>> mylist = []
>>> f(mylist)
>>> mylist
['u']
```